# How do you change remote repository name using VS Code and Github?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I accidently named my remote repo origin/main which it is now showing up as origin/main/main. So I should have just entered origin. Now I'm not sure how to change the name without doing any complicated command line args.

Comment: `git remote rename origin/main origin` is complicated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command line is not complicated. To rename a [remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), run:

```
git remote rename currentname newname
```

In your case:

```
git remote rename origin/main main
```

Comment: god bless you my dude